# JavaScript: How to call API URL as drop down list option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ionic-framework

I am under one ionic app. And I am new to this technology. Initially I have done some hard code to display one page. But in that screen I have one drop down list. When user press that drop down list of options have to show. That I have hard coded now.

But what I need is, I have one API URL. In that URL I have list of options like small,big,medium like that I have 5 option in that URL API. Now how to call that API in my drop down and to show the available option in my URL to my drop down list ??

Here my code that I have hardcode :

```
<ion-view title="MEMBERSHIP" id="page9" class=" ">
    <ion-content padding="true" style="background: url(img/4O7gypHrThaw2VZgUimX_slide1-1.jpg) no-repeat center;background-size:cover;" class="has-header">
        <form id="mEMBERSHIP-form7" class="list ">
            <label class="item item-select " id="mEMBERSHIP-select8">
                <span class="input-label">Car Type</span>
                <select>
                    <option>Small</option>
                    <option>Medium</option>
                    <option>Large</option>
                    <option>Suv</option>
                </select>
            </label>
        </form>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

My example url :  `http.exmpleurl.com/getpackages.php`

How to call this above URL API and to display the available option in my URL and to display them in my drop down list ??

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

1. Call API and get response data with `$http`.
2. Take that data in some `$scope` variable.
3. Bind response data to control in this way

`<select>
<option ng-repeat="res in response" value="res.id">{{res.name}}</option>
</select>`

Regards